# How to add new project template to Delphi

Tags: delphi, templates, delphi-2010, gallery

I remember doing this in Delphi 7, but I don't remember how, or it is different in the new Delphi IDE.  But how do I add a new template to the items gallery?

[image: Customize items Gallery]

So then it will show up under the **File** / **New** menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jim , try Project->"Add to repository..."

Comment: I knew it was something simple, but I was totally looking in the wrong place.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, from the loaded project, you would do an "add to repository" in Project menu. From there you would choose your page where it should appear.

Answer (score 1):

In the help, if you search for "Template Libraries" it gives instructions on how to do it.